# Use variable from selected row on mysql

Tags: mysql, linq

I want to use a selected row on mysql like this.
I have a query about value.

```
Select maxValue from tableOne
```

And i want to use this value on my query like that.

```
Select (Select maxValue from tableOne where tableTwo.Aa=tableOne.Aa LIMIT 1) as maxValue,CASE tableTwo.Param WHEN 1 Then maxValue -50
When 2 Then maxValue-100
When 3 Then maxValue-400
When 4 Then maxValue-500
ELSE 
maxValue
END ,
from tableTwo
```

How can i use like this ?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Add example data (place it on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com) and also add expected results.

Comment: Do you want to realize this in LinQ in i.e. C# or as a query in SQL? You tagged the question as linq.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is

```
Select 
CASE tableTwo.Param 
WHEN 1 Then t.maxValue - 50
When 2 Then t.maxValue - 100
When 3 Then t.maxValue - 400
When 4 Then t.maxValue - 500
ELSE t.maxValue
END
from tableTwo
JOIN
(   
    SELECT
        Aa
        , MAX(maxValue)
    FROM tableOne
    GROUP BY Aa
) t
    ON t.Aa = tableTow.Aa
```

Comment: I use tabletwo on tableone select where param. I cant use like that.

Comment: I Editted this query.

Answer (score 0):

You need one column, so you don't need to join, just select from table that has the column:

```
(Select maxValue from tableOne where tableTwo.Aa=tableOne.Aa LIMIT 1)
```

should be

```
(Select maxValue from tableWithMaxValue LIMIT 1)
```

and if you want to join tables, you can do this in outer query, so the whole query becomes:

```
SELECT CASE tableTwo.Param WHEN 1 Then maxValue -50
                           WHEN 2 Then maxValue-100
                           WHEN 3 Then maxValue-400
                           WHEN 4 Then maxValue-500
                           ELSE maxValue END
FROM tableOne t1
JOIN tableTwo t2 ON t1.Aa = t2.Aa
LIMIT 1;
```